# Alias/synonym for ant target

Tags: ant

I have an ant target called "unittest" which I find clunky and I would like to use "test" instead. I need to keep the name "unittest" around though because other people also use the ant build file.

Is there a way that I could add aliases or synonyms for particular targets?

I tried using a comma separated list as possible in other attributes such as `depends` but that this not work. I get `Target "test" does not exist in the project ...`

```
<target name="test,unittest">
```

I know that I could simulate this using `depends` but I want to avoid the extra unnecessary output this produces.

```
<target name="test" depends="unittest">
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I will be fine with accepting the `depends` approach if there really is no better way.

Comment: You've already got your answer.  I'm really not clear on why a couple additional lines of output is a cost.  However you could rename unittest to test and then create a stub target called unittest that dependended on test to avoid the extra output.

Comment: @thekbb That's just the reverser of what I have already suggested. It wouldn't help with the people that use the longer target name. I'd like the same output regardless of which target is used.

Answer (score 1):

Move the contents of the `unittest` target into a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) and replace the contents of the `unittest` target with a call to the macro. Create a `test` target calling the same macro. Job done.